# Airflow No module named 'wtforms.compat'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, wtforms

recently i have been trying to install airflow on my Macbook pro( 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5)

However, i have been facing persistent problems in trying to create a virtual environment(venv) where i can install airflow.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 82, in <module>
    from airflow.www.app import (cached_app, create_app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 42, in <module>
    from airflow.www.blueprints import routes
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/blueprints.py", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.www import utils as wwwutils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 36, in <module>
    from wtforms.compat import text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.compat'
```

System Description:
1.Macbook pro( 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5)
2.Python Version (3.8.12)

Possible solutions:

1. I have installed airflow in accordance to the documentation

   pip install "apache-airflow[celery]==2.2.3" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.3/constraints-3.8.txt"
2. I have tried most solutions here as well as airflow github issues. Most recommend reinstalling which i did as well. Some include changing wtforms == 2.3.3 but to no avail as well.

I have exhuasted most of my means i hope stackoverflow can guide me through this. Lastly, thank you in advance and i hope to learn from you

Comment: Have you tried using the docker image? It's easier to deploy airflow using some containers for it. check https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: @alvaroavila yes i did and it works. However, i would like to run it locally without docker.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.9 not python 3.8

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
```

Apparently for some reason you mixed those. You should make sure you both CREATE and ACTIVATE virtualenv and install airflow in the right virtualenv.

Comment: Hi jarek, thanks for responding really appreciate your time. However, i still ran with the exact same issue
`Airflow_Tutorial % python3 --version
Python 3.9.10

Airflow_Tutorial % python3 -m venv py_env

Airflow_Tutorial % source py_env/bin/activate

Airflow_Tutorial % pip install 'apache-airflow==2.2.3' \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.3/constraints-3.9.txt"

Airflow_Tutorial% airflow init db`

Comment: `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 36, in <module>
    from wtforms.compat import text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.compat'`

Comment: You have a messed instalation. The import you get is from "system installed" airflow - apparently you have airflow installed multiple times (once as system package and once as virtualenv) - you have your python installation broken. Please wipe out your whole system and reinstall airflow from the scratch